# Looking for software/device to track members of a riding group

Tags: software

We are a group of bike rider; whenever we go on a trip its been a little difficult to manage the location of all riders.

Like If somebody left behind how can we find exact location of the bike.

Do we have any **Device/Software** by which we can continues track each others location?

**Note:** If any external device is available let us know we are ready to buy this.

**Location:** if I have to be precise - **India**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is actually asking for a software recommendation. You may have better luck on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but be sure to [read about what is on topic there](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting.

Answer (score 4):

Google latitude provided you all have compatible mobile phones, wich nowerdays who doesn't?

https://support.google.com/gmm/?rd=2#topic=3495970

It will track in realtime the position of all the people you accept from your google account. [image]

Although I must point out this will only point out riders on a map, not rides.

Comment: I am a window Nokia lumia phone user so I have to try this first.

Comment: Is it available in India.... We are not able to find or download invite friend of such option in our Naxus Android Phone...

Comment: open latitude app, look @ top right, little silhuette with + sign... thats your add friends option